# reading database into app/ displaying it in listview

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to populate a listview using a database that i have saved in my assets.  I have gotten as far as checking to see if the database is being created when i run the app(which it is).  My current problem is trying to figure out how to get the columns and display them in a list view.  My columns are name,position and department, in case you see a piece of code you don't understand.  i've been trying to use code from http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html
if anybody is able to help me, I would be really grateful, Thank You in Advanced.

EDIT:  When code runs it gives me a null pointer exception

```
    public class Favorites extends ListActivity {
        public static String tableName = "fac";
        private ListView lv;
        SQLiteDatabase newDB;
        private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.favorites);

            openAndQueryDatabase();
            displayResultList();
        }

        private void displayResultList() {
            TextView tView = new TextView(this);
            tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 "
                    + "of the results are displayed");
            getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        }

        private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
            try {
                DataBaseHelper dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(
                        this.getApplicationContext());
                newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT name, position FROM " + tableName
                        + "where ", null);

                if (c != null) {
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                            String position = c.getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex("position"));
                            results.add("name: " + name + ",Position " + position);
                        } while (c.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            } finally {
                if (newDB != null)
{
                    newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
                newDB.close();
            }}

        }
    }
```

LogCat:

```
     04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cerealBarApps/com.cerealBarApps.Faculty_tab}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cerealBarApps/com.cerealBarApps.Favorites}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cerealBarApps/com.cerealBarApps.Favorites}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1651)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:656)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.cerealBarApps.Faculty_tab.onCreate(Faculty_tab.java:55)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     ... 11 more
        04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.cerealBarApps.Favorites.openAndQueryDatabase(Favorites.java:63)
04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.cerealBarApps.Favorites.onCreate(Favorites.java:25)
04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
04-24 04:43:19.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
```

Sorry

Comment: can you post your NullPointer exception trace?

Comment: if you need anything else let me know

Comment: you truncated your log exactly to a point where I wanted to see from..
I wanted to know the line number in com.cerealBarApps.Favorites class which is causing the nullpointer

Comment: sorry i just edited it.  It seems like my error is on line 63 and 25

Comment: I fixed my null pointer exception.  the problem was SQLiteDatabase newDB.  Now i still need to display that information in listview. I've learned something new about logcat today.

Comment: is your 63 line in the finally block? if yes.. put both these lines in a closure.. 
{
newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            newDB.close();
}
probably your SQLiteDatabase  is not getting instantiated..

Comment: They are in closure arnt they?

Comment: They are not in a closure for if condition.. This is just to avoid another nullpointer from finally block.
if (newDB != null){
                newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            newDB.close(); }

Comment: fixed.  Maybe it could be because my listview is coded wrong?

Comment: from your stacktrace i'd say the NPE is because the database is null when you query it

Comment: I fixed the null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this plz..
In the below statment, please put ' ' before 'where' keyword.

Old

```
Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT name, position FROM " + tableName + "where ", null);
```

New

```
Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT name, position FROM " + tableName + " where ", null);
```

Comment: Nope the problem still exists.

Comment: Please check DBHelper class is also working fine or not. Check that one is returing SQLiteDatabase instance or not..

Comment: All my db helper class does is creates the database on phone on start of application.  My table is already defined in a file saved in my assets.  All i should need to do is read this file and display in view

Comment: You try put this line Log.i("newDB", newDB) after this code newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); and please tell me the output of LogCat

Comment: I cant get that log to do anything.  It is underlining i and telling me to make newDB a string

Comment: Actually all i want to check is whether newDB is NULL or dbHelper is NULL.. if newDB is NULL, then your problem must be in DataBaseHelper class's getWritableDatabase() method.. If dbHelper is NULL, please check the code inside DataBaseHelper class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10426/discussion-between-the-obliviator-and-code-behind)